# Addition of sum of subset of two vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I found the below example in a textbook linear algebra textbook.

Suppose $U=\{(x,x,y,y)\in F^4 : x,y\in F\}$ and $W=\{(x,x,x,y)\in F^4 : x,y\in F\}$. Then,
$U+W=\{(x,x,y,z)\in F^4 : x,y,z\in F\}$.

Now, shouldn't the following be true $U+W=\{(2x,2x,x+y,2y)\in F^4 : x,y\in F\}$ instead of $U+W=\{(x,x,y,z)\in F^4 : x,y,z\in F\}$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
U + W &= \{v \in F^4 : \textrm{there is $u \in U$ and $w \in W$ such that $v = u+w$}\} \\
&= \{v \in F^4 : \textrm{there is $a,b,c$ and $d$ in $F$ such that $v = (a,a,b,b) + (c,c,c,d)$}\} \\
&= \{(a,a,b,b) + (c,c,c,d) : a,b,c,d \in F\} \\
&= \{(a+c,a+c,b+c,b+d) : a,b,c,d \in F\} \\
&= \{v \in F^4 : \textrm{the first two entries of $v$ are equal}\} \\
&= \{(x,x,y,z) : x,y,z \in F\}.
\end{align}